# Facebook Default Activity Privacy setting

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

I have a unity app with facebook login, the default permission set after login is "only me" for "Activity Privacy setting"

[image]

I need this to default to "Friends" so it can work for a leaderboard

How do I change it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, that's a user setting.

Comment: @JeanLuc yes I know in the image its a user setting, but when I installed FaceSmash (the test developer app) it preset this setting to friends.